# Why js-cookie is not working for href value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

please can someone help me with [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

here is my code which is not working:

```
// Set Default 
var names = ['car', 'bus'];

// Get Cookie
var href_name = $.cookie('href_name');

// Cookie Exists
if (href_name){
    $('#switch_style').attr(href_name);
}
// Cookie Doesn't Exist
else {

}

$('#box').on('click', function(){
    $("#switch_style").attr("href", 'bus' );    
    $.cookie('href_name', 'bus');
});
```

and here you can see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrCrE/199/)

also here is working example:

```
// Set Default Colors to Match CSS CLasses
var colors = ['black', 'red'];

// Get Cookie
var box_color = $.cookie('box_color');

// Cookie Exists
if (box_color){
    $('#box').addClass(box_color);
}
// Cookie Doesn't Exist
else {
    $('#box').addClass('black');
}

$('#box').on('click', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('black').addClass('red');
    $.cookie('box_color', 'red');
});
```

and here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrCrE/192/)

So i dont know why the first example is not working. I need when someone clicks the box, after that href is changed, and it needs to stay changed after refresh of page. but for some reason it is not working. please see first example. while the second example is working normally.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly is `$('#switch_style').attr(href_name)` supposed to achieve? This only _reads_ the current content of the attribute, but you are not doing _anything_ with that value ...

Comment: `$('#switch_style').attr(href_name)` is the getter of the attribute, but you're not doing anything with the result of that call. If you mean to use the setter you're missing the attribute name

Answer (score 2):

Just replace

```
// This is actually a getter
$('#switch_style').attr(href_name);
```

with

```
// Here we are actually setting the "href" from cookie
$('#switch_style').attr("href", href_name);
```

and your code should work fine.
Also, you are not using `js-cookie` actually here, but the old version [`jquery-cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using js-cookies wrong.

```
// Set Default Colors to Match CSS CLasses
var colors = ['black', 'red'];

// Get Cookie
var box_color = Cookies.get('box_color');

// Cookie Exists
if (box_color != ""){
    $('#box').addClass(box_color);
}
// Cookie Doesn't Exist
else {
    $('#box').addClass('black');
}

$('#box').on('click', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('black').addClass('red');
    Cookies.set('box_color', 'red');
});
```

**EDIT**
This post seem to be irrelevant because, as @palaѕн has pointed out, you're not using js-cookie